# Decompoing a special matrix into a cross product of two vectors

Tags: tensor-products, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ where all of its columns are zero vectors, except the kth column where $A_{i,k} = i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$. So my expectation is to write this matrix as the form $A = u v^{T}$ where $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ in order to apply the Sherman-Morrison formula, but I am stuck on the decomposition part. My attempt is that the matrix $A$ in general has the form:

$$
A = [ \mathbf{0} \cdots A_{i,k} \cdots \mathbf{0}] 
$$

where $A_{i,k} = [1,2,..., n]^{T}$

So I tried to rewrite this form:

$u = [0, 0 , \cdots  1 , ..., 0,0]^{T}$ where 1 appears at kth row. $v^{T} = [1, 2, ..., n]$ is a row vector.

Then $u v^{T} = B$. However, this matrix $B$ is the transpose of $A$ which I could not apply Sherman-Morrison if I want to solve a system $(C + A) x = b$ where $C$ is some n-by-n matrix in general. I really appreciate any idea and suggestion.

Comment: Swap u and v. u=(1,2,3,...) and v = (0,0,...,0,1,0,...)

Comment: Thanks!! I did not notice this